# Ebean enhancement ignores a model

Tags: java, sbt, ebean

We are using the  [avaje-agentloader](https://github.com/avaje-common/avaje-agentloader) to enhance our ebeans.  All the ebeans are in the same package.  We are including the loader, the agent & the base ebean library in our project (via sbt):

```
"org.avaje" % "avaje-agentloader" % "1.1.2",
"org.avaje.ebeanorm" % "avaje-ebeanorm" % "4.5.5",
"org.avaje.ebeanorm" % "avaje-ebeanorm-agent" % "4.5.2",
```

However, when the loader runs the enhancement, it skips ONE ebean.

Each ebean is annotated with `@Entity` and extends `com.avaje.ebean.Model`.  There seem to be no differences between the ones that get enhanced and the one that does not.  There are no extra includes, or extends, etc.

Basically, I'm wondering if anyone has run across this issue in the past, or has any insights.

Things we've tried:

- specifying actual classes to be enhanced via `serverConfig.setClasses(...)`
- specifying pakages to analyse/enhance via `serverConfig.addPackage(...)` or `setPackages(...)`
- not specifying at all and having the loader analyse all.
- we've set a break-point at `Transformer.transform` and the bean in question is never actually hit.

Note: if we use the ebean agent via an agent loader on the command line, or via a maven plugin, or sbt, it works.

Comment: I should clarify, that it seems to ignore the SAME model each time.  There are 11 beans/models in the package, and its skipping the same one each time (not the first or last).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So I posted this on the [Ebean group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ebean) on Google Groups as well, and **Rob Bygrave** responded, explaining a few things. (read his reply [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ebean/UL0GfwyFvHA/51C7bAMT5g0J))

1. `serverConfig.setXXX` have nothing to do with ebean enhancement.
2. It looks like the bean is being loaded before the agent loads.

He was correct, indeed the model/bean in question is being loaded well before the agent.  So we are tracking down why.

The issue therefore is that the agent does not enhance beans that have already been loaded by the ClassLoader (makes sense).  he did mention that we could "*Change the Ebean agent to also support 'class redefinition'*".